# TwinCAT3 AdsWarning 4115: system clock setup fail

Tags: twincat

I've got problem with TwinCAT3 (Win10 64bit) when I try to active TC3.

Error message is :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
>   19-Jan-19 11:42:34 AM 545 ms | 'TwinCAT System' (10000): Sending ams
>   command >> Init4\RTime: Start Interrupt: Ticker started >> AdsWarning:
>   4115 (0x1013, RTIME: system clock setup fails.  Hint: On Windows8
>   system and above execute win8settick.bat in TwinCAT\3.1\System as
>   administrator and reboot.) << failed!

I also try to run "win8settick.bat" and reboot TC but it doesn't work!

Is there any recommend to solve this ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please provide some more information about what hardware you're using (computer manufacturer, processor) and which version of Windows 10 you're running (LTSB, Professional, Home, etc)?

Answer (score 11):

I have had the problem few times. In all those situations, the BIOS settings have been OK. Executing the .bat file didn't help, until I ran it as an administrator and rebooted. Few times I have had to do it couple of times before it started working.

So try this

1. Open start menu and search for "Command prompt"
2. Right click it and select run as administrator
3. Navigate to "C:\TwinCAT\3.1\System" by writing "cd C:\TwinCAT\3.1\System"
4. Execute .bat by writing "win8settick.bat"
5. Reboot - Repeat if not working

For me, this has always fixed the problem. If you have incorrect BIOS settings, you would get different error that states something about virtualization (as far as I know).

Comment: I did the same thing and it didn't work right away because I then got an error that the network adapter was not working so I disabled the network adapter and then enabled it again and ensured it was selected properly as per https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf6311_tc3_tcpudp/9007200361328779.html&id=. After that, it worked for me again

Comment: I was skeptical that doing the same thing the second time would make a difference, but it did! TwinCAT switches to run mode now.

Comment: This Worked for me. You may have to run it as Admin. Also,  keep in mind that this will trigger the bitlock security (if you or your company enable it) so be prepared with the log key or IT support. Else you wont be able to boot into windows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust your BIOS-settings according to:
http://www.contactandcoil.com/twincat-3-tutorial/quick-start/

(read chapter BIOS settings).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, you'll get this error if you haven't setup the real-time cores to match the computer you're activating to:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may have Hyper-V enabled. Because of the way that 64-bit TwinCAT interacts with the processor (using Intel VT-x), it doesn't play well when hypervisors are running at the same time. Most hypervisors, like VMware, stop running when you close their window. However, Hyper-V (if enabled) is always running in the background so it must be disabled before using TwinCAT.

To Enable or Disable Hyper-V:

1. Right click on the Windows button and select ‘Apps and Features’.
2. Select Programs and Features on the right under related settings.
3. Select Turn Windows Features on or off.
4. Check or Uncheck Hyper-V and click OK.

[image: Screenshot of Windows Features Window, arrow pointing to Hyper-V checkbox]

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, installing **TwinCAT 2** on top of an existing **TwinCAT 3** installation was the problem.

According to Beckhoff, you need to "deactivate" TwinCAT 3 via "SwitchRuntime.exe" before installing TwinCAT 2, if installed in this order. In case of installing TwinCAT 3 on top of TwinCAT 2, you don't need this step.

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_installation/179471755.html&id=

If forgot this, which probably destroyed parts of my TwinCAT 3 installation in the background.
Even tough I set the installation directory to a new folder "*C:\TwinCAT\TwinCAT_2*" and not the default "*C:\TwinCAT*".
The installation process locked fine at first, only after trying to set a project into RUN while having TwinCAT 3 active as runtime, I got the above mentioned "AdsWarning: 4115".

Running "win8settick.bat" as admin and rebooting did not help, neither via explorer or command line.

Only **re-installing TwinCAT3** did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to disable the `Virtual machine platform` in Windows Features.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issues. But I didn't try any of the above methods.
bcz I am scared about warning 'BitLocker trigger' from a user above!

Then I changed the real-time system settings:

error :

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       27/08/2022 16:40:58 279 ms | 'TwinCAT System' (10000): Sending ams command >> Init4\RTime: Start Interrupt: Ticker started >> AdsError: 4115 (0x1013, RTIME: system clock setup fails.
Hint: On Windows8 system and above execute win8settick.bat in TwinCAT\3.1\System as administrator and reboot.) << failed!

settings:  shared core 80%
[image: old setting_shared core]

new real-time setting: Isolated core 100 %
[image: new setting _isolated core]

No error:
[image]

I didn't know the reason behind this!