# TWINCAT 3 BECKHOFF CONFIGURATION PROBLEM CHANGING RUN MODE

Tags: runtime, ads, plc, twincat

I have a problem trying to change to run mode when the target device is the PLC (in local mode the problem disappears). It gives me the error: AdsError: 4115 (0x1013, RTIME: system clock setup fails). I have tried to execute win8settick.bat as administrator and rebooting so many times. I have checked the Hyper-V config and BIOS visualizator too. There is nothing that works for me. Any idea? Thank you

Comment: Hi Javier. Welcome to StackOverflow. You mentioned that you tried a few things already. Have you tried all of the suggestions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264180/twincat3-adswarning-4115-system-clock-setup-fail)?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, I did. I tried all of that without success. Since yesterday there is no error given back but Twincat doesn't change to run mode yet, it stays in config mode and give me that 'Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Message  17/09/2021 11:44:40 829 ms | 'TwinCAT System' (10000): TwinCAT System Restart initiated from AmsNetId: "IP number" port 32979.    
'

Answer (score 0):

Ive only had this problem when trying to start it locally.

But one problem might be that the PLC time is way off. One suggestion to start troubleshooting would be to check the actual time on the PLC.

You can do this by either remotely accessing it via RDP or by plugging in a monitor and keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds for me like a incompatibitility between TwinCAT-Realtime-System and the hardware. More exatly the CPU. What type of hardware do you use on your target system? Is it Beckhoff-Hardware or Third-Party. If third-party, which CPU?
Another topic could be the TC-Version related with the Target OS. Can you provide more information about this.